# I Insert values in stock.picking move_lines but after click on save it Error The Following fields are in valid stock.move in odoo10

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, odoo-10

This button

```
                        <span class="o_stat_value"><field name="test_field"/>Material Out</span>
```

```
class SkylineJobOrder(models.Model):
    _name = 'skyline.job.order'
    _inherit = 'purchase.order'


    @api.multi
    def action_workorder_out(self):
        x = 0
        """ This opens the xml view specified in xml_id for the current Work Order in Manufacturing """
        self.ensure_one()
        xml_id = self.env.context.get('xml_id')
        if xml_id:
            res = self.env['ir.actions.act_window'].for_xml_id('stock', xml_id)
            production = self.env['mrp.production'].search([('product_id','=',self.product_id.id)])
            for item in production:

                x = item.bom_id.id
            bomline = self.env['mrp.bom.line'].search([('bom_id','=',x)])
            for record in bomline:


                res.update(
                    context={'default_states':'draft','default_partner_id': self.partner_id.id,'default_move_lines': [(0,0, {'address_in_id':self.partner_id.id,'product_id':record.product_id.id,'product_uom': record.product_uom_id.id,'product_uom_qty':record.product_qty,'scrapped':False,'state':'draft','picking_id':False,'name': 'test','procurement_id': record.operation_id.id,'split_from': self.id,'no_open': True,'no_create':True,'availability':1,'location_dest_id':8,'picking_id':35})]}
                )

            print res
            return res
        return False
```

> I inherit purchase.order and create a button and put action of
>   stock.picking . The working of button is to stockout the values of raw
>   material of product .so when click on save button is shows that the
>   following fields are invalid stock.move.

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote
>   value inserted form bom.line.ids to stock.move through stock.picking using picking_id, location_id,lication_dest_id and 'purchase=ok, in purchase_id.